# Continuous Distribution Probability Question

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, combinations, normal-distribution

**The Question**

Apple produces about 300 iPads every hour at their factory in Silicon Valley. On average, about 2.5 % are found to be defective. What is the probability that exactly 4 iPads will be defective?

So I've tried approaching this two different ways but I'm getting two different answers and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**First Approach**

mean = 7.50

standard deviation = 2.7

P(3.5<x<4.5) = P(-1.48<z<-1.11) = 0.1335 - 0.0694 = 0.0641

**Second Approach** - using combinations

P(x=4)=300C4(0.025)^4 (0.975)^296
= 0.072

Okay so I know these answers are slightly different to due the approximation in the first approach. Can someone confirm these answers are correct though?

Comment: For the first, it looks like you're using the [normal approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation) to the binomial distribution. The second is using the binomial distribution. The first is an approximation of the second, so it makes sense that the values you're getting aren't exactly the same but are close.

Comment: "Can someone confirm these answers are correct though?" - @Jac  Yes, I have not checked the calculations, but the numbers input, and the methods, are correct.   [Although there is a typo  in the approximation; the second $x$ should be $z$ (as it is the standard normal variable; rather than the original).]

Comment: I have edited my answer to reflect the edit in your question.

Answer (score 2):

The first approach is using the normal *approximation* to the binomial distribution, while the second approach the exact answer using the binomial distribution. There is no reason to expect the approximation to equal the exact answer.

Your second approach is exactly correct. Your first approach is correct as well; I have verified you found approximately correct $z$ values of $-1.48$ and $-1.11$, and that these $z$-values convert to the probabilities you claimed.